# Append custom line to cherry-picked commits in range

Tags: git, cherry-pick

When cherry-picking a range of commits I can use [`-x`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--x) to append the line "(cherry picked from commit [commit])" to each commit message.

How do I customize this line to instead say "Backport of [commit] from master" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-e` or `--edit` with your `git cherry-pick` command; this will invoke your chosen editor on the commit message.  You can then change the appropriate line manually.

If you want to automate the commit-message change, choose as your "editor" a script / program that will:

- open the file whose name is passed as an argument;
- find and replace the line;
- write the result back to the file whose name was passed; and
- exit with a zero status to signal success.

Do this just for the one `git cherry-pick` command, by setting `$GIT_EDITOR` (environment variable) or `core.editor` (Git configuration setting) for the duration of the one command:

```
GIT_EDITOR=<path/to/script> git cherry-pick -x -e <commit-specifier>
```

or:

```
git -c core.editor=<path/to/script> cherry-pick -x -e <commit-specifier>
```

(Consider using `sed -i ""`, for instance, to construct the editor-script.)